# Why is home page content not displaying with this rewrite rule?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, mod-rewrite

I am trying to pass a variable from a URL to PHP using mod_rewrite while maintaining standard WordPress functionality.

Here's my mod_rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /index.php?state=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

When I go to this URL:
http://epiclasers.com/arizona/

It is obviously being handled by index.php (because the theme is being loaded) and the state variable is being passed to PHP.  but I am having trouble getting the home page content to be displayed - instead it is showing 404 "page not found" content.

Can someone shed some light as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

When I redirect using the R flag, it works as it should:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /index.php?state=$1 [R,L]
```

and the home page is served:  http://epiclasers.com/?state=arizona

It seems that WP is grabbing the URL using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to process requests/queries - and WP is getting confused by the /arizona/ in the URL?

Let's just assume that mod_rewrite is functioning correctly.  Does anyone know how to customize WordPress to ignore "/arizona/" in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up figuring this out.  Like I thought, the problem had nothing to do with mod_rewrite and everything to do with WordPress.

To solve the issue, I had to use the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['state'])) {
$url = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = end($url);
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = "/" . $url;
}
```

This code in essence removes the "/arizona/" from the REQUEST_URI global and replaces it with "/", which then forces WP to serve up the front page template from the index.php file.  Fixed!

Perhaps a few of you can vote this answer up for me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you've forgotten the QSA directive, to add properly the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ /index.php?state=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Tell me if it works, and if not, I'll do my best to answer.

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Hi Oliver.  I tried that, but it didn't change anything.  I am still getting a 404.  The only query I am passing is the "state" one, and that is going through fine.  I'm thinking this has something to do with the way WP processes requests/queries directly from the URL?

Comment: I've added my two usual hints. May I ask you to add the tracelog to your question as well?

Comment: Newer versions of mod_rewrite apparently use "LogLevel". I get internal server errors when I try to use any of those Mod_rewrite logging directives.  this is from my error log:

/home/epiclasers/epiclasers.com/.htaccess: LogLevel not allowed here

Comment: In your global config, make sure you have the directive **for this directory** "**`AllowOverride All`**". Then if you have "**`Options +FollowSymLinks`**" in your htaccess, comment it. Then restart your server. Note: this is temporary, only to use rewritelog file, **don't forget to go back to the original state once you're done with the problem**.

Comment: global config?  This is just a virtual host - the only way I can configure anything is via .htaccess files.  I already spoke with my web host and they do not allow mod_rewrite logging for virtual host clients.  Again, I don't think there is any problem with mod_rewrite - it seems to be working exactly as it should.

Comment: if this is a virtual host, it's somewhere in a directory on your harddisk, right? So, in your global configuration (i.e. not the `vhost`, but usually the **`httpd.conf`** file), add the rights `AllowOverride All`. Then... if you have "Options +FollowSymLinks" in your htaccess, comment it. Then restart your server. Note: this is temporary, only to use rewritelog file, don't forget to go back to the original state once you're done with the problem.

Comment: I don't think you understand - this domain is a virtual host on a shared server at a web hosting company.  I don't have access to the httpd.conf file, nor can I restart apache.  Like I said above, I can't enable mod_rewrite logging.

Comment: Okay! You just wrote "this domain is a virtual host", you didn't precise "on a shared server at a web hosting company", so I thought you had a configuration like mine: a full dedicated web server.

Comment: so, assuming mod_rewrite is working properly, do you have any other possible solutions?

Comment: "assuming mod_rewrite is working properly" is the problem. Did you try a simple rewriterule in the first place like `RewriteRule . http://disneyland.com [R=301,L]` to redirect everything to disneyland? If this rule doesn't work then don't go further. If it does, then we can go on.